# Is it possible to request buffer of particular size using buffer protocol?

Tags: python, buffer, cython

I'm trying to understand how to use buffer protocol, here's a bit of code that's supposed to write a chunk of Base64 encoded text into a buffer:

```
cpdef object encode_base64(object fin, object fout):
    if not PyObject_CheckBuffer(fin):
        raise TypeError("fin must follow the buffer protocol")
    if not PyObject_CheckBuffer(fout):
        raise TypeError("fout must follow the buffer protocol")

    cdef Py_buffer in_view
    cdef int ret_code = PyObject_GetBuffer(fin, &in_view, PyBUF_SIMPLE)
    if ret_code < 0:
        return

    cdef Py_buffer out_view
    out_view.len = in_view.len;
    ret_code = PyObject_GetBuffer(fout, &out_view, PyBUF_SIMPLE)
    if ret_code < 0:
        return

    cdef size_t written;

    cdef bytes py_bytes = "1. out.buf: %s, out.len: %d\n".encode()
    cdef char* c_string = py_bytes
    printf(c_string, out_view.buf, out_view.len)

    cdef size_t used = encode_buffer(
        <unsigned char *>in_view.buf,
        in_view.len,
        <unsigned char *>out_view.buf,
        out_view.len,
        80,
        80,
        &written,
    )

    out_view.len = written;

    printf(c_string, out_view.buf, out_view.len)

    print "used: {}, written: {}, out: {}".format(used, written, printbuf(fout))
```

`encode_buffer()` is defined elsewhere in C code like this:

```
size_t encode_buffer(
    const unsigned char* buf_in, const size_t buf_in_size,
    const unsigned char* buf_out, const size_t buf_out_size,
    const size_t pre_pad, const size_t padding, size_t* written);
```

It works properly (at least in my understanding).

The problem is that if I then use this code in Python in this way:

```
def test_printbuf():
    buf_in = BytesIO(b'1234567890')
    buf_in.seek(0)
    buf_out = BytesIO()
    buf_out.seek(0)
    encode_base64(buf_in.getbuffer(), buf_out.getbuffer())
    buf_out.seek(0)
    print('Encoded: {} -> {}'.format(buf_out.getbuffer(), buf_out.getvalue()))
```

The `buf_out` appears to be empty.  (I probably write the encoded text into some memory I'm not supposed to touch, but that's not the main problem right now).

My problem is: how can I get the buffer of the size I want from `BytesIO`?  Since it was initialized with an empty string, it has a zero-length buffer, and it ignores the `len` field of `Py_buffer` struct.

I looked at the implementation of `BytesIO`, and it has special functions for resizing its buffer, but they are specific to this object, and I want my code to be generic.

Comment: I think in the generic case, buffers are not resizable, so perhaps you would be better off allocating your out buffer inside the cython function, then returning a `memoryview` object that could be consumed generically?

Comment: @chrisb well, I also looked into Python's source for how they implemented `base64.encode()`, and they allocate on heap all the time, and then call `write(allocated bytes)`. In fact, seeing this, I decided to try to do it using buffers, hoping that I could avoid heap allocations... and, in principle, there's no problem with that: when writing to actual files OS will allocate memory to put your contents into it. It's strange that in Python they didn't think about that.

Comment: @wvxvw If you did manage to resize the buffer then that would end up being a heap allocation. But more importantly the buffer interface is just designed give quick access to a block of memory that's already been allocated so it isn't the tool for the job. Why don't you just allocated the correct size in a `BytesIO`?

Comment: @DavidW (1) That's not really what I'm asking: I'm asking for API to request a buffer of certain size. This is quite possible to achieve without heap allocation. (2) The problem is, actually the unnecessary copying of bytes: my primary use case is writing to actual files, and there OS already allocated whatever memory required. (3) `BytesIO` is just an example. I'd like the code to work for any object that implements buffer protocol. If this was specific for `BytesIO` the problem would've been much simpler (I could just call its `write()` method).